# SSH error on Debian 8.2 (DigitalOcean Droplet)

Tags: ssh, debian

I have a problem with SSH on my new droplet..

```
root@srv2:~# shutdown -h now
[SSH] ERROR: Read from remote host 46.101.84.179: Connection reset by peer
[SSH] FAIL: Write failed: Broken pipe
[SSH] INFO: DISCONNECT
```

and the same problem with reboot (the reboot and shutdown will not run, I have to force them from the DigitalOcean CP)

With the old server (`sr1v1.lucavasini.it`) I have no problem...

I use Mac OSX and ZOC7 terminal.

Comment: Look at the console to see what is happening.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply... I am not very skilled, where I have to look at exactly? Thanks

Comment: what is the problem? When you restart or shut down your system, you loose the ssh connection to it.

Comment: Maybe it takes more time to reboot, than what you expect. Do you have any virtual console, or sth to see what is going on during reboot?